# DataAnnotations for valid email address

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using data annotations for my form where users can register their account. For the email field I have one data annotation for required and one for a valid email. Here you can see that in my viewmodel:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Email field is required.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The Email field is not a valid e-mail address.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

In my view I have the following code:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="RegisterAsync" method="post" class="register-form">
    <br />
    <img src="~/images/logo.png" width="300" />
    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="text-danger">
        @ViewBag.FailedToRegister
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="Name" placeholder=@Localizer["Name"] class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="Email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
// Removed code for brevity
```

Now when I run my app and leave the email field empty I get a nice error message like below.

[image: Correct email error message]

But when I fill in something that is not a valid email address then I don't get the same error text like above but I get the following.

[image: Wrong email error message]

(Sorry for the dutch message, it means: A valid email address is required.)

But why don't I get the message that I programmed in my ViewModel and how do I fix this?

I also tried to change

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The Email field is not a valid e-mail address.")]
```

in my viewmodel to

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "The Email field is not a valid e-mail address.")]
```

, but without luck.

Comment: Which version of ASP.Net MVC are you running?

Comment: @AshokanSivapragasam .NET Core 2.1

Comment: Check this Example: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Email-model-validation-with-DataAnnotations-and-DataType-In-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unexpected validation you are seeing is coming from your browser. If you add the "novalidate" attribute to your form it will disable it:

e.g.

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="RegisterAsync" method="post" class="register-form" novalidate>
```

Comment: I still get the same thing like before

Comment: Does novalidate attribute not disable the client-side validations?

Comment: it should only disable the browser validation, not the MVC client side validation

Comment: ideally you should have both working ie jquery + server side to be safe